# Scrapy/XPath: Replace inline tags within paragraph

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to use *Scrapy* to extract and clean some text from within `p` which contains inline icons and other tags. In particular, I want to replace the image tags with text extracted from the image `src` attribute:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
text = '''
<p id="1"><b><br></b>For service <i>to </i>these stations, take the <img src="images/1.png"> to 72 St or Times Sq-42 St and transfer
    <br>to an uptown <img src="images/1.png"> or <img src="images/2.png"> <i>local</i>.
    <br>
    <br>For service <i>from </i>these stations, take the <img src="images/1.png"> or <img src="images/2.png"> to 72 St or 96 St and transfer
    <br>to a South Ferry-bound <img src="images/1.png">.
    <br><b>______________________________<br></b>
</p>
'''
sel = Selector(text=text)
# do stuff
```

The result I'm looking for is the string:

> For service to these stations, take the (1) to 72 St or Times Sq-42 St and transfer to an uptown (1) or (2) local. For service from these stations, take the (1) or (2) to 72 St or 96 St and transfer to a South Ferry-bound (1).

I can extract the text from `src` using:

```
node.css('img').xpath('@src').re_first(r'images/(.+).png')
```

but I'm stuck on how to iterate through the child nodes and determine if it is a text node / how to filter out the other inline tags. Here's where I'm at:

```
description = sel.css('p#1')

def clean_html(description):
    for n in description.xpath('node()'):
        if (n.xpath('self::img')):
            yield n.xpath('@src').re_first(r'images/(.+).png')
        if (n.xpath('self::text()')):
            yield n.css('::text')

text = ''.join(clean_html(description))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I don't think `selectors` are particularly helpful.

Try processing this in two phases.

1. Use `re.sub` to substitute the entire `img` tag with the string you
   want.
2. Use `BeautifulSoup` to remove the remaining HTML from the resulting string.

Like this:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# manually construct a selector for demonstration purposes
DATA = '''
<p id="1"><b><br></b>For service <i>to </i>these stations, take the <img src="images/1.png"> to 72 St or Times Sq-42 St and transfer
    <br>to an uptown <img src="images/1.png"> or <img src="images/2.png"> <i>local</i>.
    <br>
    <br>For service <i>from </i>these stations, take the <img src="images/1.png"> or <img src="images/2.png"> to 72 St or 96 St and transfer
    <br>to a South Ferry-bound <img src="images/1.png">.
    <br><b>______________________________<br></b>
</p>
'''
sel = Selector(text=DATA)

# get the raw source string to work with
text = sel.extract()

# replace image tag with text from extracted file name
image_regex = re.compile('(<img src="images/)(.+?)(.png">)', re.MULTILINE)
replaced = re.sub(image_regex, r'(\2)', text)

# remove html and return clean text
soup = BeautifulSoup(replaced, 'lxml')
print(soup.get_text())
```

Results:

> For service to these stations, take the (1) to 72 St or Times Sq-42 St
>   and transfer
>       to an uptown (1) or (2) local.
>
> For service from these stations, take the (1) or (2) to 72 St or 96 St
>   and transfer
>       to a South Ferry-bound (1).
>       ______________________________

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it without any additional external library:

1. Get text and image paths:

   `results = selector.xpath('.//text()|.//img/@src').extract()`
2. Remove extra spaces, new lines and underscores:

   `results = map(lambda x: x.strip('\n_ '), results)`
3. Remove empty strings:

   `results = filter(None, results)`
4. Join results into a single paragraph and fix dots:

   `raw_paragraph = " ".join(results).replace(' .', '.')`
5. Replace `images/{Number}.png` with `({Number})`:

   `paragraph = re.sub('images/(?P<number>\d+).png', '(\g<number>)', raw_paragraph)`

Result: `For service to these stations, take the (1) to 72 St or Times Sq-42 St and transfer to an uptown (1) or (2) local. For service from these stations, take the (1) or (2) to 72 St or 96 St and transfer to a South Ferry-bound (1).`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I accepted @jschnurr answer as bs4 is how I ended up solving the issue myself. Plus I feel its better to stay in the DOM rather than manipulating directly as strings (that's way I was struggling with scrapy's built-in selectors!)